# How To Pass JSON Response to my ArrayList in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I am new to ios swift. Here I Have a jsonResponse, which has came from my web service. Now I want to parse this response to my array. Here is my code of model class.

```
 struct OrderItem:Codable{
let purchaseId : Int
let purchasedDate: String
let purchasedStatus: Int
let purchasedItems: [String]
```

}

Here my response from my webservice.

```
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error)-> Void in
            do{
//                let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! Array<Any>
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                self.orderMenu = try! decoder.decode([OrderItem].self, from: data!)
                print("===122===",self.orderMenu)
            }catch{
                print("ERROR")
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.MytableView.reloadData()
            }
        }).resume()
```

this is my jsonResponse

```
[
{
    "purchaseId": 19,
    "purchasedDate": "2018-07-27 23:48",
    "purchasedStatus": 0,
    "purchasedItems": [
        {
            "purchasedItemsId": 72,
            "purchasedCount": 2,
            "purchasedPrice": 34,
            "purchasedGST": 3,
            "itemDescription": "abcd2",
            "itemCategoryDescription": "Cloths_Type_6",
        },
        {
            "purchasedItemsId": 73,
            "purchasedCount": 3,
            "purchasedPrice": 44,
            "purchasedGST": 9.1,
            "itemDescription": "Item2",
            "itemCategoryDescription": "Flags",
        },
        {
            "purchasedItemsId": 74,
            "purchasedCount": 4,
            "purchasedPrice": 123,
            "purchasedGST": 3,
            "itemDescription": "Item3",
            "itemCategoryDescription": "Food",
         },
        {
            "purchasedItemsId": 75,
            "purchasedCount": 5,
            "purchasedPrice": 42,
            "purchasedGST": 9.1,
            "itemDescription": "Item4",
            "itemCategoryDescription": "Flags",
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Some One please get me a solution, Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: show json......

Comment: Actually the JSON is parsed into an array. What is the issue you have? And aren't you concerned about the *`'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block`* warning? By the way: **never ever** print a meaningless literal string like `"ERROR"` in a catch block, print the actual `error`.

Comment: @HiteshAgarwal , I added my json. Please check

Comment: what is your issue ??

Comment: how to get the data object into array data in tableview, When i am getting data in array will not getting is the name of (purchasedItems)

Answer (score 0):

`purchasedItems` is an array of dictionaries, for the dictionary you have to create another struct

```
struct OrderItem : Decodable {
   let purchaseId : Int
   let purchasedDate: String
   let purchasedStatus: Int
   let purchasedItems: [PurchasedItem]
}

struct PurchasedItem : Decodable {
   let purchasedItemsId, purchasedCount, purchasedPrice : Int
   let purchasedGST : Double
   let itemDescription, itemCategoryDescription : String
}
```

Then you can print for example the `itemDescription` from `orderMenu` with

```
for order in orderMenu {
    for item in order.purchasedItems {
      print(item.itemDescription)
    }
}
```

And - once again – print **always** the error instance in the `catch` block

```
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: According to the code the array of `OrderItem` is properly decoded. Please describe what you are going to accomplish.

Comment: When i am trying to decode the below response i have getting, in that  PurchasedItem will get empty array. 
[POSApplication.OrderItem(purchaseId: 21, purchasedDate: "2018-07-28 00:04", purchasedStatus: 0, purchasedItems: [])]

Comment: If you are using exactly my structs the decoding must work. What error do you get? **Print the `error`**

Comment: its getting the data currently, How to get the  "PurchasedItem" same like orderItem.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: i am trying to you are given struck it will be working,But i need to get the purchasedItems array to how to get the elements like as order items. below i have tried the i have get the response.  for items in self.ordemenu{ items.purchasedItems } , how to get the purchasedItems data.

Comment: It's in my answer. Please see the snippet `for order in orderMenu { for item in order.purchasedItems {...` and then access the properties of `item` you need

Comment: how to change the array count of purechese items on evry position.

Comment: Once again *Please describe what you are going to accomplish*. Your questions are a bit foggy. What is *array count*? What does *position* mean? Change *where*?